# Prevent PLT (procedure linkage table) breakpoints in GDB

Tags: c++, c, debugging, gdb, breakpoints

In recent versions of GDB, setting a breakpoint on a library function call results in multiple actual breakpoints:

1. Call into the procedure linkage table (PLT)
2. The actual function call

This means that when the library function is called, we end up going through two breaks each time.  In previous GDB versions, only #2 would be created and hence you only get one break.

So the question is: can one can create a library function call breakpoint without the corresponding PLT breakpoint?  I am aware that you can create a regular breakpoint and then explicitly disable the PLT one, but this is really tedious.

Answer (score 8):

I think I found a solution for this problem. You can use the

```
break *address
```

syntax of break, but instead of specifying a hex address, you give the name of the function (which evaluates to the function's address). Something like

```
break *myfunction
```

That sets a breakpoint only on the main function, and not any of the PLT versions.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work for me; the "break *myfunction" breakpoint was never hit :(

Comment: DIdn't work for me either.  Got 'No symbol XXX in current context.'

Answer (score 5):

add these lines to your `~/.gdbinit` file and call `disaplts` to disable all `@plt` breakpoints:

```
define disaplts
  python
import gdb
from StringIO import StringIO
lines=gdb.execute("info break", True, True)
for l in StringIO(lines).readlines():
  if "@plt" in l:
    bp=l.split()[0]
    gdb.execute("disa {0}".format(bp))
    print("disabling {0}".format(bp))
  end
end
# disable on library load
catch load mylibrarywithplt disaplt
```

Note: mind the spacing in python code. I recommend you use `cat` to paste the content.
EDIT: added "execute on library load" per @WallStProg

Comment: Nice -- thanks!  Note that if there are pending breakpoints you'll need to run this AFTER the library is loaded -- e.g.:  

`catch load <libname>`  

`commands`  

`disaplts`  

`end`

Comment: oooh, nice... added it.

Answer (score 3):

Yup, it can be done.

To simply place breakpoints on all functions, use command:

1. **rbreak .***

So, this will place breakpoints on all the functions including PLT.

Now type:

2. **save breakpoints filename**

This will save a list of all breakpoints in a file called as **filename**.

3. Now open the file in normal text editor like **gedit**, and **remove** all the **PLT** lines given at the end of the file. And then save the file with only the required functions on which you want to place breakpoints.

**or**

3. Remove all the **@plt** from the function names using the command:

**sed 's/@plt//g' filename > newfilename**

4. After this, **exit gdb** (to unlink gdb from useless PLT breakpoints, added before) and **execute gdb again**.

Now type command:

5. **source filename**

**or**

5. **source newfilename** (in case you used sed command)

At this point, gdb will put breakpoints only on the functions mentioned in the file called as "**filename**" or "**newfilename**" (if used sed).

**Note:** To filter functions more in the file **"filename"**, one can use grep also according to the requirements. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a command, `rdelete`, that is like `delete` in the same way that  `rbreak` is like `break` - it deletes breakpoints based on a regexp argument.

```
$ cat rdelete.py
import gdb
import re

class RDelete(gdb.Command):
  """Delete breakpoints for all locations matching REGEXP."""

  def __init__(self):
    super (RDelete, self).__init__ ("rdelete", gdb.COMMAND_BREAKPOINTS, gdb.COMPLETE_LOCATION)

  def invoke(self, argstr, from_tty):
    bppat = re.compile(argstr)
    for bp in gdb.breakpoints():
      if bppat.search(bp.location):
        print("Deleting breakpoint {} at {}".format(bp.number, bp.location))
        bp.delete()

RDelete()


$ gdb -q hoist
(gdb) rbreak .*
...
(gdb) i b
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address            What
1       breakpoint     keep y   0x0000000000000580 in main at hoist.c:6
2       breakpoint     keep y   0x00000000000007a0 in x at hoist.c:4
3       breakpoint     keep y   0x0000000000000530 <_init>
4       breakpoint     keep y   0x0000000000000560 <printf@plt>
5       breakpoint     keep y   0x00000000000007b0 <__libc_csu_init>
6       breakpoint     keep y   0x0000000000000820 <__libc_csu_fini>
7       breakpoint     keep y   0x0000000000000824 <_fini>
(gdb) source rdelete.py
(gdb) rdelete @plt
Deleting breakpoint 4 at printf@plt
```