# Prevent PLT breakpoints on overloaded methods

Tags: c++, gdb, breakpoints

```
struct O {
    O();
    O(int);
    O(O const&);
};
```

I'm using `gdb` to debug a C++ program, and I want to set breakpoints on all the overloaded methods of a class, (in this case the constructor) e.g. `break O::O`. However, this also sets breakpoints in the PLT (procedure linkage table) if `O` is implemented in a library.

I tried to apply https://stackoverflow.com/a/33675845, but that didn't work:

```
(gdb) break *O::O
non-unique member `O` requires type instantiation
```

Granted, there isn't a single `O::O` so `*` probably can't decide between them.

Is there a way to make this work, or do I have to resort to the other suggestion (create all the breakpoints and then disable the @plt ones : https://stackoverflow.com/a/42095773) ?